# Replacement has 0 rows, data has 25 error

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a list containing 25 different passwords to check against another list of 50, and come back with the matches. This is for a university project on passwords. The idea is the list of 25 are the most commonly used passwords, and I would like R to tell me which of my 50 passwords match the most common 25. However I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "Percent", value = character(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 25
```

I am using the following code

```
makeCounts <- function(x) {
  return(x=list("count"=sum(grepl(x, Final_DF$pswd, ignore.case=TRUE))))  
}

#creates a local variable named tmp which is removed afterwards
printCounts <- function(ct) {
  tmp <- data.frame(Term=names(ct), Count=as.numeric(unlist(ct)))
  tmp$Percent <- sprintf("%3.2f%%", ((tmp$Count / nrow(Final_DF$Pswd) * 100)))
  print(tmp[order(-tmp$Count),], row.names=FALSE)
}

# create top 25 mostly commonly used pswds

worst.pass <- c("password", "123456", "12345678", "qwerty", "abc123", 
                "monkey", "1234567", "Qwertyuiop", "123", "dragon", 
                "000000", "1111111", "iloveyou", "1234", "12345", 
                "1234567890", "1q2w3e4r5t", "ashely", "shadow", "123123", 
                "654321", "superman", "sunshine", "tinkle", "football")

worst.ct <- sapply(worst.pass, makeCounts, simplify=FALSE)
printCounts(worst.ct)
```

The data containing my 50 passwords are is contained in my data frame Final_DF$Pswd and is as follows

```
> Final_DF$Pswd
 [1] "monkey"       "iloveyou"     "dragon"       "jbI2pnK$xi"   "password"     "computer"     "!qessw"      
 [8] "tUNh&SSm6!"   "sunshine"     "wYrUeWV"      "superman"     "samsung"      "utoXGe6$"     "master"      
[15] "wjZC&OvXX"    "0R1cNTm9sGir" "Fbuu2bs89?"   "pokemon"      "secret"       "x&W1TjO59"    "buster"      
[22] "purple"       "shine"        "flower"       "marina"       "Tg%OQT$0"     "SbDUV&nOX"    "peanut"      
[29] "angel"        "?1LOEc4Zfk"   "computer"     "spiderman"    "nothing"      "$M6LgmQgv$"   "orange"      
[36] "knight"       "american"     "outback"      "TfuRpt3PiZ"   "air"          "surf"         "lEi2a$$eyz"  
[43] "date"         "V$683rx$p"    "newcastle"    "estate"       "foxy"         "ginger"       "coffee"      
[50] "legs"
```

Show traceback of the error when I run `printCounts(worst.ct)` reads

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Percent", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 25 
4.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
    "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA) 
3.
`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Percent", value = character(0)) 
2.
`$<-`(`*tmp*`, "Percent", value = character(0)) 
1.
printCounts(worst.ct)
```

I have read a couple of forum posts, and I am not sure if this has something to do with NA values? I am new to R and been looking at this for some time scratching my head.

Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
> dput(Final_DF)
structure(list(gender = c("female", "male", "male", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male", "male", 
"female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "female", "female", "male", "female", 
"female", "male", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male"), age = structure(c(47L, 43L, 65L, 24L, 
44L, 60L, 26L, 25L, 62L, 23L, 44L, 61L, 27L, 47L, 18L, 23L, 34L, 
77L, 71L, 19L, 64L, 61L, 22L, 55L, 45L, 29L, 21L, 64L, 43L, 20L, 
32L, 55L, 68L, 21L, 81L, 43L, 63L, 72L, 38L, 20L, 66L, 39L, 64L, 
20L, 73L, 21L, 53L, 75L, 69L, 82L), class = c("variable", "integer"
), varname = "Age"), web_browser = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Chrome", 
"Internet Explorer", "Firefox", "Netscape"), class = c("variable", 
"factor"), varname = "Browser"), Pswd = c("monkey", "iloveyou", 
"dragon", "jbI2pnK$xi", "password", "computer", "!qessw", "tUNh&SSm6!", 
"sunshine", "wYrUeWV", "superman", "samsung", "utoXGe6$", "master", 
"wjZC&OvXX", "0R1cNTm9sGir", "Fbuu2bs89?", "pokemon", "secret", 
"x&W1TjO59", "buster", "purple", "shine", "flower", "marina", 
"Tg%OQT$0", "SbDUV&nOX", "peanut", "angel", "?1LOEc4Zfk", "computer", 
"spiderman", "nothing", "$M6LgmQgv$", "orange", "knight", "american", 
"outback", "TfuRpt3PiZ", "air", "surf", "lEi2a$$eyz", "date", 
"V$683rx$p", "newcastle", "estate", "foxy", "ginger", "coffee", 
"legs"), pswd_length = c(6L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L), last.num = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should provide `Final_DF` using `dput`, read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: Likely candidates of a duplicate, [`[r] replacement has 0 rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+replacement%20has%200%20rows).

Comment: Should `nrow(Final_DF$Pswd)` instead be `nrow(Final_DF)`? If it is a simple column, then that it guaranteed to return `NULL`.

Comment: BTW, having your function rely on an external variable neither defined within nor passed to the function is a bad idea: it breaks reproducibility, and it can make troubleshooting difficult. One quick option is to add an argument to `printCounts(ct, finaldf)` and call it with `printCounts(worst.ct, Final_DF)`.

Comment: @r2evans that makes a difference in that it prints the term, count and percentage but it is not recognising the matches just appears with 0 count for all

Comment: `Final_DF$pswd` should be `Final_DF$Pswd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that appear wrong with your functions.

1. `makeCounts` is referencing `pswd`, but `Final_DF` has `Pswd` and `pswd_length`. R is doing a partial match for, and I'm guessing that it is not the one you want. Let's prove what it is using, first by setting an option[1]:

   ```r
   options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE) # see ?options
   worst.ct <- sapply(worst.pass, makeCounts, simplify=FALSE)
   # Warning in Final_DF$pswd : partial match of 'pswd' to 'pswd_length'
   # Warning: partial match of 'pswd' to 'pswd_length'
   # Warning: partial match of 'pswd' to 'pswd_length'
   # Warning: partial match of 'pswd' to 'pswd_length'
   # Warning: partial match of 'pswd' to 'pswd_length'
   ### ...repeated...
   ```

   Worse, if you look at this variable (part of troubleshooting your problem is to check the variables you are making and using), you'll see that it is effectively empty/useless, where all values are `0`:

   ```r
   str(worst.ct)
   # List of 25
   #  $ password  :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   #  $ 123456    :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   #  $ 12345678  :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   #  $ qwerty    :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   ### ...truncated...
   ```

   If you change your function to use the correct column name, it provides no such warning, and it does contain some non-zero elements:

   ```r
   makeCounts <- function(x) {
     return(x=list("count"=sum(grepl(x, Final_DF$Pswd, ignore.case=TRUE))))  
   }
   table(unlist(worst.ct))
   #  0  1 
   # 19  6 

   str(worst.ct)
   # List of 25
   #  $ password  :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 1
   #  $ 123456    :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   #  $ 12345678  :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   #  $ qwerty    :List of 1
   #   ..$ count: int 0
   ### ...truncated...
   ```
2. Within your `printCounts` function, you are referencing `nrow(Final_DF$Pswd)`, which is always going to produce `NULL`. Have you tried this?

   ```r
   nrow(Final_DF$Pswd)
   # NULL
   nrow(Final_DF)
   # [1] 50
   ```

   Instead, rewrite that line to be

   ```r
     tmp$Percent <- sprintf("%3.2f%%", ((tmp$Count / nrow(Final_DF) * 100)))
   ```
3. Not a syntax error, but your function relying on a variable that is neither defined within it nor passed to it is bad practice: it means the function can behave differently when the same parameters are passed to it, which breaks reproducibility (and it can make troubleshooting rather difficult).

   I suggest making `Final_DF` an argument for the function, and passing it every time.

   ```r
   printCounts <- function(ct, Final_DF) {
     tmp <- data.frame(Term=names(ct), Count=as.numeric(unlist(ct)))
     tmp$Percent <- sprintf("%3.2f%%", ((tmp$Count / nrow(Final_DF) * 100)))
     print(tmp[order(-tmp$Count),], row.names=FALSE)
   }

   printCounts(worst.ct)
   # Error in nrow(Final_DF) : argument "Final_DF" is missing, with no default

   printCounts(worst.ct, Final_DF) # no error here
   ```

   For this case, I'm recommending that you do not provide a default value for it. This also enabled you to use the same function with different "final" frames of passwords, in case you are testing (unit-testing) or testing (train/test sampling) or testing (troubleshooting).

After those changes, I get this:

```r
printCounts(worst.ct, Final_DF)
#        Term Count Percent
#    password     1   2.00%
#      monkey     1   2.00%
#      dragon     1   2.00%
#    iloveyou     1   2.00%
#    superman     1   2.00%
#    sunshine     1   2.00%
#      123456     0   0.00%
#    12345678     0   0.00%
#      qwerty     0   0.00%
#      abc123     0   0.00%
#     1234567     0   0.00%
#  Qwertyuiop     0   0.00%
#         123     0   0.00%
#      000000     0   0.00%
#     1111111     0   0.00%
#        1234     0   0.00%
#       12345     0   0.00%
#  1234567890     0   0.00%
#  1q2w3e4r5t     0   0.00%
#      ashely     0   0.00%
#      shadow     0   0.00%
#      123123     0   0.00%
#      654321     0   0.00%
#      tinkle     0   0.00%
#    football     0   0.00%
```

---

Note:

1. I have `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE, warnPartialMatchAttr=TRUE)` set in my `~/.Rprofile` (and any project-specific `.Rprofile` init file) for just this reason: the `$` *silently* does partial matching, and this can be very problematic. With the warning, at least you can *see* what R is inferring in the background. There is a third option, `warnPartialMatchArgs`, that has the same intent ... but waaaaaaaaaay too many package authors out there are inadvertently relying on this behavior, so lacking the time/ability to fix them all, I have chosen to muffle this noise-maker.

   Especially if this partial-matching behavior is a surprise to you, I strongly encourage you to set the first two options yourself. In the best-case, it produces no warnings and you have the comfort of knowing that you are taking steps to produce more resilient code; at worst, it is noisy and you eventually get tired of the noise and fix the lazy code.

   See [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) for these three among many other available options. (Packages can set their own options as well; an option is similar in concept to Windows' registry, for better or worse, in that it is global to R, and can have arbitrary keys and values.)

Comment: Thanks, your changes worked, in summary to check my understanding this was all down to duplicate pswd names in the one DF? `options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)' what does this line of code do, is it helping us to pin point the problem?

Comment: (1) You had two errors in your functions. (2) That option set helps identify where one of the problems is, the other error was evident when you step line-by-line through your code. To learn more about that option, see [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) and search for `warnPartialMatchDollar`; I could copy/paste here, but it's best to find the authoritative docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to check whether a (set of) password(s) is in a set of bad passwords, you could use

```
Final_DF$Pswd %in% worst.pass
```

This will give you a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE`. you could run `sum(Final_DF$Pswd %in% worst.pass)` to get the total number of bad password matches, or `table(Final_DF$Pswd[Final_DF$Pswd %in% worst.pass])` for a quick overview of matches.

However, if your intention is to check a set where passwords are constantly added (which I'm guessing is the intention, since you made the functions), the following might be useful:

```
result <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Final_DF$Pswd)) {
    if (Final_DF$Pswd[i] %in% worst.pass) {
        result[i] <- which(worst.pass == Final_DF$Pswd[i])
    } else
        result[i] <- NA
}
table(worst.pass[result[!is.na(result)]])
```

The results is a table with the count of the matches. In your case,

```
  dragon iloveyou   monkey password sunshine superman 
       1        1        1        1        1        1
```

Note that for large amount of passwords looping is not advisable. In that case, neat `tidyverse`approaches would be worth looking at.